# Breeding Limited Dragons

Tags: dragonvale

If I'm breeding a Limited Dragon (and I'm sure I have it because of the time on timer), will I still get the dragon if it expires and is removed from the market before breeding is done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the only thing that's limited is the time you can *start* breeding the dragon. If you bred a Leap Year dragon on the right day but didn't hatch it until after the event (without using gems you *have* to hatch it after the event time) you still get your time limited dragon. The same goes for eggs; once the dragon has been determined (at the time you start breeding) you'll get to keep the dragon after the time expires.